# Simple-Salesforce query error cannot find field

Tags: python, python-3.x, salesforce, soql, simple-salesforce

I am using Simple-Salesforce to query records via .query_all, but when I include a recently created custom field, I receive the `No such column` error.

An example of the query that creates the error is below, with `Problem_Field__c` as a stand-in for my field.

```
s.query_all('SELECT ID, Name, Problem_Field__c FROM Custom_Object___c')
```

I have already reviewed the field-level security of this field and do have access to it.

As additional information, my login to the sandbox in which I am using this custom field is below:

```
s = simple_salesforce.Salesforce(username='myUsername.TestDomain',
                                 password='myPassword',
                                 organizationId='mySandboxOrgId',
                                 security_token='',
                                 domain='test')
```

The problem field is a lookup field to the `Contact` object.

Comment: Check if your user's Profile has Read access to Contacts. If it's a lookup you end up with "I can see the field but not the table for which it's a foreign key" and this might throw some query errors too. Is it a normal field or part of some managed package (does it have namespace in front of it, `xx__Field__c`)? Your user might not have license for the package (although in sandboxes it's rarely a problem)

Comment: Have you tried running the query from the Developer Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

A lookup is a relationship between two objects. When you use a relationship in a query and the query is navigating the relationship in a child-to-parent direction (Contact = parent, your custom object = child), you must use the relationship names. Custom relationships are named with an `__r` rather than `__c` suffix ([docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm)). The relationship name is typically the same as the API name of the lookup on Lookup definition screen but with suffix replaced. Your query should be

```
s.query_all('SELECT ID, Name, MyRelationship__r.Some_Contact_Field FROM Custom_Object___c')
```

To know the relationship name for sure, you can use [take a look at the object schema](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315335&type=1&mode=1).

Comment: A lookup field that is queried directly should return the Id of the record referenced in that field. The `__r` annotation is not required for this type of query. `SELECT ID, Name, MyRelationship__c FROM Custom_Object__c` would return a value with the MyRelationship__c id values, but should not return a `No such column` error unless the field does not exist or the person querying does not have access to the field

Comment: @Jwok That is true although it's not crystally clear from your question you're after a relationship id. `simple-salesforce` implements `query(...)` as a REST API call to `/services/data/v38.0/query?q=...` .  If you login to Workbench via your sandbox user account and try this, you should be able to determine if it's a permission or naming issue.